# Why does God let people kill each other?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, belief, children

We are all here in this world to pass our test, and the other world will be the result of our deeds in this world, right??

Then if God gave us the chance of test here in this world. Why did he gave others the ability to take away **that chance** from us?? Specially when people can kill a child before he even gets the ability to think?!!

Yes, you may say that's also part of the test!! But what about that other dead guy who loses the chance to grow up and do good deeds and **have a higher degree in the other world?**

Comment: Oops! Well done, you asked indeed a significant question which I hear it from many people. Actually it is heard that many people ask why does He let people kill each other. A nice answer would be so helpful. / Although my brief answer is that: it is considered as a part of the testing of humans.

Answer (score 4):

God decided to create and send humans to earth (by sending Adam to earth) in a form that some of them being enemy of some others. So because of this form of creating humans so they naturally create each other.

> [Allah] said, "Descend from Paradise - all, [your descendants] being
>   enemies to one another. And if there should come to you guidance from
>   Me - then whoever follows My guidance will neither go astray [in the
>   world] nor suffer [in the Hereafter]. http://tanzil.net/#20:123

Such nature is needed for testing humans. At end of this verse God talks about guidance and testing humans.

Humans have worldly greed. One of them is defeating the enemy. Humans love to kill his enemy. But when God says you should not kill that enemy of yourself, this is a test of God. Without such natures testing humans will not be possible.

Regarding a child killed and losing the possibility of higher ranks after death we are not sure that they really lose that rank. Perhaps God recovers this losing of possibility of reaching higher ranks and grants that ranks to that killed child without even worshiping God in worldly life.

In fact, this question has an assumption about God (God will not let killed children to have higher ranks at hereafter) that it is not known to be true.

> O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed,
>   some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other. Would
>   one of you like to eat the flesh of his brother when dead? You would
>   detest it. And fear Allah; indeed, Allah is Accepting of repentance
>   and Merciful. http://tanzil.net/#49:12

There are different hadiths saying such children will enter paradise.

---

**Reference:**

[Will the children killed by prophet Khizr a.s. enter the paradise?](http://maaref.porsemani.ir/node/1531)

Comment: thanks, I read your ref too!! But `without even worshiping God in worldly life` then isn't it unjust for that child to be judged?? based on things he didn't do!! then we would all may want to be killed in childhood to at least not go to hell.

Comment: @Bludream no it is not unjest. because no human has the right to go paradise even with obeying God. "unjust" is applicable only when there is a right. from our creation to paradise all is mercy of God. not our right. http://tanzil.net/#29:21 God wanted to you remain alive and that child not remain alive! any problem? http://tanzil.net/#21:23

Comment: If that's so, then why does he even care to test us?? He knows already what we do and we don't have to judge any of his actions! Then isn't it pointless to take a test from us???

Comment: @Bludream this is a separate issue. please ask it in a new question. comments are not suitable.

Comment: @Bludream asking new question is better. because other users can use your Islamic research too. do you eat cakes yourself alone? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why does God let people kill each other? because He already kill us all, what is the difference between dying in a bed, in a war or by cancer? it's the same death.

We are born with zero information and therefore God is not responsible for what we learn and what we choose to do.

Now imagine when we were young stealing money/chocolate/etc from our mothers, or when we had to lie, did God have to intervene and punish you? Or are you still young and you are learning and need another chance? There is no doubt that you will reject the punishment and will demand an extension of the exam period.

In the exam, the teacher does not interfere with what the student does, but leaves him to the end of the exam period and holds him accountable, as well as God does, there is no sense to hold the student accountable in the middle of the exam (the earth).

God sometimes sends people to other people to kill them, yes, this is normal because God kills us with many enemies, such as cancer, viruses, and aging, not just because of humans. The world is a small hell, so that man may know that God is capable of creating more evil than the world, which is hell.

now, the important question is why we die? we die because we are just in an examen, earth is a school not the house. we die to leave place to others, so they can  pass the examen like us, because the earth cannot bear the immortality of man, it is too small for that. The last man to enter Paradise will have what equal to the earth twice! so imagine what the first man to enter Paradise will have, and how big is the Paradise (the Heaven)...

> Ibn Mas'ud reported: Verily the Messenger of Allah said: **The last to enter Paradise would be a man who** would walk once and stumble once and be burnt by the Fire once. Then when he gets beyond it, he will turn to it and say: Blessed is He Who has saved me from thee. Allah has given me something He has not given to any one of those in earlier or later times. Then a tree would be raised up for him and he will say: O my Lord I bring me near this tree so that I may take shelter in its shade and drink of its water. Allah, the Exalted and Great, would say: O son of Adam, if I grant you this, you will ask Me for something else. He would say: No. my Lord. And he would promise Him that he would not ask for anything else. His Lord would excuse him because He sees what he cannot help desiring; so He would bring him near it, and he would take shelter in its shade and drink of its water.
>   ...
>   ...
>   He (Allah) would say: O son of Adam, what will bring an end to your requests to Me? **Will it please you if I give you the whole world and a like one along with it**? He will say: O my Lord! art Thou mocking at me, though Thou art the Lord of the worlds? Ibn Mas'ud laughed and asked (the hearers): Why don't you ask me what I am laughing at. They (then) said: Why do you laugh? He said: It is in this way that the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) laughed. They (the companions of the Holy Prophet) asked: Why do you laugh. Messenger of Allah? He said: On account of the laugh of the Lord of the universe, when he ldesirer of Paradise) sai Thou mocking at me though Thou art the Lord of the worlds? He would say: I am not mocking at you, but I have power to do whatever I will.

I cut the hadith to shorten it