# Why did God leave Satan free and allow him to mislead people, but do not the religious people allow us to deceive people?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, shaitan

Why do not be free to sell alcoholic beverages, honey (without hijab), homosexuals, sexually crafted, showing and distributing porn movies, all those who tempt us, while we are not forced to do anything?

Why do some Islamic governments or some religious people, temptations, and those who, contrary to their religious beliefs, restrict and compulsorily prevent their activities? while God left Satan free and allowed him.

`On the other hand, why did God leave Satan free?`

Is human paradise worthless in the absence of Satan, or parable of man among temptations and deceiters? (freely)

Comment: Articulate more and fix your phrases. I couldn't get past your first sentence.

Comment: "Why do some Islamic governments or some religious people" would be off topic. However you could rephrase yourself a bit, take a look at the question: [Why does God let people kill each other?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12745/15201), please edit your question.

Comment: I mean that, why Satan (شيطان) is free to tempting us, but we are not free to tempting some others?(Islamic government forces as flogging and ... for without hijab (scarf), who eating foot in Ramezan and creating porn movies and etc...

Comment: Editing suggestions for my question with fluent ones is appreciated.

Comment: -1 What are you trying to say? "***Why do not be***" ... "***honey (without hijab)***" ... "***sexually crafted***" ... "***all those who tempt us, while we are not forced to do anything?***" ... "***temptations, and those who, contrary to their religious beliefs***" ... "***Is human paradise worthless ... or parable of man among temptations*** " ... "***for without hijab (scarf), who eating foot in Ramezan***"

Comment: I try say: (1)- someone may force us for doing bad acts(terrorist). (2)- Someone may tempt us, and not force. (Satan) => If Allah (ﷻ) let Satan been free for tempting us, why Islamic government  not let `tempter`s been free?

Comment: I have removed the bounty on this question; it *really* needs a lot more work on clarity and focus before it's ready to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Allah (ﷻ) doesn't approve of what Satan is doing so please do not be mistaken. Satan is carrying on out of his own free will. Free Will is given to everyone - whether the Jinn (including Iblis/Satan) or humans. Humans have the free will to deceive/disobey too.. and indeed many of them do deceive their fellow man out of their free will.

Is Satan truly "free" in what he is doing, i.e., without consequences? Of course not!!! He is cursed per the Qur'an and his eternal abode will be Hell. Likewise, any person in this Dunya who follows in Satan's footsteps will be there with him in Hell. THIS is why Muslim countries are not "free" to allow alcohol, homosexuality, etc.. because a great punishment will overcome them if they allow such evils which Allah (ﷻ) forbid. **Satan *chose* that path of doom; Muslims do not**. It's that simple.

Comment: (1) In above I said Allah (ﷻ) approve Satan's doing? (2) Please bring an example of Satan addressed as cursed  in Qra'an.(3) In "if they allow such evils which Allah (ﷻ) forbid.": Is Allah (ﷻ) "forbid" or "force"?, Is Muslim countries "forbid" or "force"?

Comment: (1) If you acknowledge that Allah doesn't approve in either case, then you understand that Satan isn't doing anything "free". So saying his actions are "freely" done was wrong to begin with because they come with consequence ie severe punishment [Hell] like with everyone else. (2). In Qur'an 16:98, Allah said.. seek refuge from Satan "الرجيم" (Al Rajim) = the accursed/expelled from God's Mercy, etc.

Comment: (3). Allah said, "The truth is from your Lord, so whoever wills - let him believe; and whoever wills - let him disbelieve" (18:29). He permits disbelievers to do whatever they want [free will]. Just as he permits Satan the disbeliever to do whatever he wants. No difference. You are comparing unbelievers to believers, but believers choose the path of belief which entails commandment to do what is right.

Comment: (1) What is the limits of Satan in tempting for mislead us as I said "*God leave Satan free and allow him to mislead people*"? (Please not that *action* and *tempting to mislead* are different.) (2) Your mean is cursed  is equal fired? ("لعن" = "الرجيم"?). (3) In Islamic government, what governors do with who are disbeliever, when they have to be *without Hijab, sell alcoholic beverages, play porn movies* and etc?